# como hacer que mi funcion retorne los salarios de un departamento que se le de como parametro?

Tags: sql, oracle

hola he creado una función de SQL en Oracle ,que al darle un numero de departamento me retorne los salarios del departamento dado ,pero al ejecutar la función esta solo toma el primer salario y lo repite aquí les dejo el script

```
create or replace function salario_emp
return number
as
cursor c1 is select  salary  
from employees 
where  department_id =50;
--variable que alamacenara el valor del cursor
v_salario number;

begin 
open c1;
loop
FETCH c1 into v_salario;
return v_salario; exit;
end loop;
close c1;
end;
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y vos que esperas que devuelva? porque aca dice que devuelve un numero.

Answer (score 0):

Hola las funciones en ORACLE están diseñadas para devolver un solo valor. Considera utilizar una vista, este componente si permite retornar un conjunto de valores.

Más información aquí:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CREATE-FUNCTION.html#GUID-156AEDAC-ADD0-4E46-AA56-6D1F7CA63306

Saludos.

Comment: gracias por el aporte hermano el link me servirá para ocasiones futuras

Answer (score 0):

Estimado

1. En el momento que pones:

> return v_salario; exit;

Ya te saliste de tu bucle, por eso obtienes el primer valor. Lo que debes hacer es cargar el valor en una variable y fuera del bucle retornar esta variable.

2. No tienes un tipo de objeto que retorne varios valores, puedes retornar un cursor al cuál cargarle los datos en el loop, o retornar una tabla (aquí un ejemplo).
   https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/databases/Oracle/PL-SQL/collection-types/return-table-from-function/index

Incluso si te complica lo anterior puedes crear un string concatenado y separar los valores por un caracter como | por ejemplo, luego retornar el string de los valores concatenados que sería algo como "1200|1240|1000" y este lo puedes reconvertir, siempre hay muchas posibilidades.

Trata de desarrollar el sp con estos tips y me cuentas como te va.

Comment: muchas gracias  por el aporte Cristian sonara divertido pero luego de hacer la pregunta me percate del problema y hice justamente lo que explicaste mas arriba y funciono XD